# rotating and translating polygon in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, geometry

I am trying to rotate a shape, then translate in the same function using the following code however, only the translation works.  Does anyone know how to make it so both transformations occur? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib as mpl
from math import *

#some helper values
p=4
theta=pi/6
x1 = p*cos(theta/2)
y1 = p*sin(theta/2)
vertices =[(-x1-p/2,0), (-p/2, y1), (p/2, y1), (x1+p/2, 0), (p/2, -y1), (-p/2, -y1)] 
midPoint = [3,4]

#set up the plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#function to rotate and translate the standard shape to a new position
def plot_polygon(vertices, midPoint, theta):
    polygon = patches.Polygon(vertices, color="red", alpha=0.50) 
    r = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate(theta) + ax.transData
    t = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().translate(midPoint[0],midPoint[1]) + ax.transData
    polygon.set_transform(r)
    polygon.set_transform(t)
    ax.add_patch(polygon)

plot_polygon(vertices, midPoint, theta)

plt.xlim(-30, 30)
plt.ylim(-30, 30)

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you set `a = 3` and later `a = 4`, at the end `a` will be `4` and not 7.*

By setting the transform via  `.set_transform` you overwrite the previously set transform, whatever comes last is the transform that is used.

You therefore need a single call to `set_transform`, using a combined transform, e.g.

```
r = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate(theta)
t = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().translate(midPoint[0],midPoint[1])
tra = r + t + ax.transData
polygon.set_transform(tra)
```